# progress bar on linux

Tags: python, linux, progress-bar

I created a python script just need some help ammending it. basically, i want the python script to allow me to view the progress of a specific log file which is created when data is being moved to a database, or the progress of a specific background job in linux.

```
 from time import sleep
 import sys

 for i in range(21):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')

    # the exact output you're looking for:

    sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*i, 5*i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: What exactly is you question?

Comment: i want the python script to allow me to view the progress of a specific log file which is created when data is being moved to a database. this is in linux. im new to python so not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Nadia Alramlis terminal progressbar for my python projects and it works great. The files you need can be found here : https://github.com/mnlhfr/moodlefetch (I could not find the original blog she posted about the use of these files). Download terminal.py and progressbar.py and use them like this:

```
from progressBar import progressBar
from time import sleep
import sys

progress = progressBar(color='green',width=30)

for i in range(21):
    p=int(i/21.0)*100.
    message="Finished with %s percent"%(p)
    progress.render(p,message)
    sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: so after downloading these two scripts and the one you wrote, how to i call the script to show the progress of the log file or a job/processes running on unix background

Comment: i keep on getting this error in unix when doing "python Script.py" which is the one you wrote above.

Warning: tparm() returned NULL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from progressBar import progressBar
ImportError: cannot import name progressBar

Comment: It seems your script is unable to find the file progressBar.py. Make sure that file is in the directory where you try to run Script.py

Answer (score 0):

use progressbar modules

Download it from

http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/

Comment: follow this article. http://thelivingpearl.com/2012/12/31/creating-progress-bars-with-python/